# Use MacRuby Debugger in Xcode?

Tags: debugging, xcode4, macruby

Is there anyway to use the MacRuby debugger macrubyd when developing a MacRuby app within Xcode?

As far as I can tell you can't do so even from the terminal. I've thought of kludgy work around but I wanted to double-check the situation before I burnt any time on it.

Using MacRuby 0.10 and Xcode4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MacRuby mailing list, there is no debugger support yet for MacRuby in Xcode.